# Is it a good or bad idea to show a countdown timer on a redirect page?

Tags: users, redirect

We have to show a redirect page when users click on links that leave our domain. Currently, we have a 5 seconds count down timer on our redirect page that basically says you are leaving our site.

My question is is it a good idea to show a countdown or not?

I am not going to debate the good/bad ux of redirect pages.

Comment: I would consider not having a timer at all. If the purpose of the redirect page is to warn the user and remove responsibility from yourself if anything should happen to the user on those other sites then you ideally want to ensure that the user has fully read the warning before proceeding. Some people will need longer that 5 seconds to do that. In my experience it seems quite standard to just have a "yes I am sure, proceed" link on the page that the user can click when they are ready to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's good UX to have a countdown timer as part of the [Visibility of System Status heuristic](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/visibility-system-status/). If the system is counting down to redirect the user, the user should know how much time they have to back up and cancel if they need to.